# Cannot Clone Bitmap after Stream Disposed

Tags: c#, directx, slimdx

I load a bitmap from a DataStream.  I try to return the loaded bitmap from a method, and later use it as a source to clone a new bitmap.  Unfortunately, the Clone() call results in an OutOfMemoryException.  Through testing I realized that Clone() succeeds until the underlying data stream is disposed.

How can I create a bitmap that exists independent from the stream it was loaded from?

```
DxScreenCapture cap = new DxScreenCapture();
var surface = cap.CaptureScreen();

Bitmap png;
Rectangle rect;
PixelFormat fmt;
using (DataStream stream = Surface.ToStream(surface, ImageFileFormat.Bmp))
{
    png = new Bitmap(stream);

    fmt = png.PixelFormat;
    rect = new Rectangle(911, 170, 32, 14);

    // Works
    Bitmap rgn1 = png.Clone(rect, fmt);
}
// Throws OutOfMemoryException
Bitmap rgn2 = png.Clone(rect, fmt);
```

Comment: GDI+ codecs are lazy, they only access the raw image store when they have to.  Kaboom with a lousy exception when you closed the stream and try to use the Bitmap anyway.   Clone() is not a workaround, it is a shallow copy.  If you don't want to keep track of the lifetime so you can delay closing the stream then you must make a copy.  Use stream.CopyTo() to copy it into a MemoryStream, don't bother disposing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Building on Hans' comment, I simply created a new bitmap from the original one.

```
Bitmap copy;
using (DataStream stream = Surface.ToStream(surface, ImageFileFormat.Bmp))
{
    Bitmap orig = new Bitmap(stream);
    copy = new Bitmap(orig);
}

// Able to use copy after stream is disposed
```